# Using static const char* const instead of #define

Tags: c++

I get the error `error: ‘Name’ was not declared in this scope`
What am I missing here.

Source File:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "scr.h"
using namespace std;

const char* const Test::Name;  

void Test::Print()
{
    cout<<Name;
}

int main()
{       
    Test *t = new Test();
    t->Print();
    delete t;   
}
```

Header File:

```
class Test
{   
    static const char* const Name = "Product Name";
    public:
        void Print();
};
```

EDIT:

If I replace `char* const` with `int`, it works. Why?

```
static const int Name = 4; //in header

const int Test::Name;  //In source
```

The purpose of the code is to have an alternate for `#define` as mentioned in Effective C++. In the example there, `static const int` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `initialize` members in class definition.

Take a look at Parashift post -   [Can I add = initializer; to the declaration of a class-scope static const data member?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.13)

> SUMMARY: The caveats are that you may do this only with `integral` or
>   `enumeration` types, and that the initializer expression must be an
>   expression that can be evaluated at compile-time: it must only contain
>   other constants, possibly combined with built-in operators.

Comment: @cod3r - Read the link I've posted.

Comment: @cod3r -Thanks! Glad you got it useful. I'm a big admirer of ParaShift.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize a static member variable within a class. Not even in the header file.

Header File:

```
class Test
{   
    static const char* const Name;
    public:
        void Print();
};
```

In your cpp file:

```
const char* const Test::Name = "Product Name";
```

Edit:
I must have added that the initialization is allowed only for int and enumerations and that too with constants that can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't initialize static variables directly in the class definition, you have to do it in a separate source file, like this:

```
const char* const Test::Name =  "Product Name";
```

An exception is integral constants, which are allowed to be in the class definition.  An easy workaround is to use a static member function instead:

```
struct Test {
  static const char *Name() { return "Product Name"; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment of the string to the source/implementation file (.cpp).